# Is changing your data from long form into wide form by summing it a valid statistical analysis step?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, dataset

If for example i have a data set of multiple stores that looks something like this:

`+---------+-----------+-------+----------+
| StoreID | Customers | Sales | Date     |
+---------+-----------+-------+----------+
| 1       | 2         | 100   | 1/1/2018 |
| 1       | 5         | 200   | 2/1/2018 |
| 2       | 1         | 50    | 1/1/2018 |
| 2       | 10        | 300   | 2/1/2018 |
+---------+-----------+-------+----------+`

Would it make sense to group up everything by storeID so as to have one row per storeID in order to perform statistical analysis on the data set?

Making it look something like this:

`+---------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
| StoreID | Customers | Sales | Date              |
+---------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
| 1       | 7         | 300   | 1/1/2018-2/1/2018 |
| 2       | 11        | 350   | 1/1/2018-2/1/2018 |
+---------+-----------+-------+-------------------+`

Comment: No reason why you should not do that but it is not what people usually mean by transforming from long to wide format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as @mcdewey pointed out, this is not usually what people mean by "long to wide"; that usually refers to creating a data set with a lot more variables and fewer observations.

Second, adding up the data in the way you suggest doeesn't violate any statistical rules, but it loses a lot of information and changes the nature of the questions you can ask about the data.  You would now be able only to ask about totals.  Whether that is a good idea depends on what you are trying to find out.

Comment: (+1) It's just a case of what defines an observation (case, record, item, whatever) for the researcher's purpose. In the question the data arrive as daily observations for each store and they're combined as totals for each store. **_Aggregation_** is one of many words that might be used. Changes between long and wide format (structure, layout) generally are rearrangements of the data, not reductions.

Comment: Thank you for all of your responses. I am really new to statistics and just wanted to ensure that Aggregating up the data would still allow me to perform hypothesis statistics. I found that aggregating values up to keep "participants" to a per row level, easier to understand based on the examples i have found.  Your answers are very appreciated and have helped me a lot.